# Determine if within a PGF axis environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, pgfplots, pgf-core

Is there an easy way to test whether a macro is called from within an PGF `\begin{axis}...\end{axis}` environment? One solution would be to define a new environment myself that sets a flag at `\begin{axis}` and clears it as `\end{axis}`, but I'd prefer not to have to do that.

Comment: interesting, is there a concrete example where one may need this?

Comment: I have defined a macro to label certain points in my graph. Since the sytnax changes whether I am within the `axis` environment or not, I want to use the same macro in my code and have it expand to different code. Is this not a good approach?

Comment: @alfC: One concrete example now at [new command, pfgkeys within pfgplots axis environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102339/4301).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pgfplots` provides a command `\pgfplotsifinaxis` that tests whether the key `pgfplots@is@in@axis` is defined and invokes code according to the outcome.

It is defined in `pgfplots.code.tex` as

```
\long\def\pgfplotsifinaxis#1#2{%
    \pgfutil@ifundefined{pgfplots@is@in@axis}{#2}{#1}%
}%
```

It is used as

```
\pgfplotsifinaxis{code if in axis}{code if outside axis}
```

Comment: Works great. Is there a way to look this kind of thing up without looking through the code? I can't find any mention of it the 2.10 TikZ-PGF manual.

Comment: @Unfortunately no, I think, there's no manual for the implementation side of things. The code is quite well commented, though.

Comment: I think I was too quick to accept this solution. This seems be defined in an `{axis}` environment, but is also defined outside? Am I using it incorrectly? See MWE added to original question.

Comment: @Peter: It should be used as `\pgfplotsifinaxis{code if inside}{code if outside}`.

Comment: Yes, that works much better.

Comment: @Peter: I removed your MWE, in order to avoid confusing people who have the same problem and look for a solution here. @Jake: Maybe you can add how the macro is used to your answer.

Comment: @Caramdir: Done!